# Can't start my apache service

Tags: apache

I can't start my Apache on Xampp, only the apache service won't run but the Mysql works fine.
When i trry to run the Apache I get this error:

> Warning: terminating working thread 0

please help guys. I'm still working on my project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try quitting skype before launching Apache.